# Account linking with Google Sign-In: "Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience"

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-signin, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, account-linking

I'm trying to make account linking with Google sign-in Linking type. For conversation using Dialogflow. To get user information, fulfillment in node.js was written, using this guide https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in. But when authorization occurs and every time I call any intent on backend, it throw next error:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GdeI.jpg)

Below is my fulfillment code.

```
`const app = dialogflow({debug: false, clientId: CLIENT_ID});
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
conv.ask('Welcome to number echo! Say a number.');
});

app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', conv => {
conv.ask(`I didn't understand. Can you tell me something else?`)
});

app.intent("Start Signin", conv => {
conv.ask(new SignIn("Sure"));
});

app.intent("Finish login", async (conv, params, signin) => {
if (signin.status === "OK") {
    const {payload} = conv.user.profile;
    conv.ask(`${payload.given_name}, now you are signed in.`);
} else {
    conv.ask("You need to sign in to personalize.");
}
});

app.intent("Show User Profile", async conv => {

const {payload} = conv.user.profile;
if (payload) {
    conv.ask("Below is your profile information:");
    conv.ask(`Your first name is ${payload.given_name};\nYour last name is ${payload.family_name};\nYour email address is ${payload.email}`);
} else {
    conv.ask("Not signed in yet.");
    conv.ask(new SignIn("To personalize"));
}
});`
```

I expect executing without error but there is an error below:
Error: Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience

Please, help me if you familiar with this error.

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been resolved. This was caused by a wrong client_id parameter in 
   dialogflow({debug: false, clientId: CLIENT_ID});

Comment: can you tell from where i can get my client id

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya if you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/ and open your project. Select Credentials and look under OAuth 2.0 for New Actions on Google App the client id is listed there.